# What's the shortcut for renaming a file in Thunar?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar

Pretty simple, what's the shortcut for renaming in Thunar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This particular shortcut is displayed in the Edit menu:

[image]

You can enable [editable accelerators](http://docs.xfce.org/faq) to easily change it.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it because it wasn't in the right-click menu

Answer (score 3):

It's <kbd>F2</kbd>.

And in fact here's the whole `~/.config/Thunar/accels.scm` with all the shortcuts:

```
; Thunar GtkAccelMap rc-file         -*- scheme -*-
; this file is an automated accelerator map dump
;
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/sendto-desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/create-folder" "<Primary><Shift>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarShortcutsPane/sendto-shortcuts" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-side-pane-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/paste-into-folder" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-home" "<Alt>Home")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open" "<Primary>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/go-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-file-system" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/zoom-out" "<Primary>minus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/paste" "<Primary>v")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open-with-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/help-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/file-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open-with-other-in-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/detach-tab" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open-in-new-tab" "<Primary><Shift>p")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-by-name" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-menubar" "<Primary>m")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/back" "<Alt>Left")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/close-tab" "<Primary>w")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-as-compact-list" "<Primary>3")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-side-pane-tree" "<Primary>e")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/restore" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-network" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1459954455527318-1" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/Tap::create-archive" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/new-tab" "<Primary>t")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/preferences" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/rename" "F2")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-by-size" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/sendto-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/edit-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open-with-other" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-location-selector-toolbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/invert-selection" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/make-link" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-as-icons" "<Primary>1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/new-window" "<Primary>n")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/forward" "<Alt>Right")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/move-to-trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/select-by-pattern" "<Primary>s")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/about" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/contents" "F1")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-desktop" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/close-all-windows" "<Primary><Shift>w")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/zoom-in" "<Primary>plus")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/duplicate" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-parent" "<Alt>Up")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-side-pane-shortcuts" "<Primary>b")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/reload" "<Primary>r")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-templates" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/copy" "<Primary>c")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-location-selector-pathbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-descending" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/properties" "<Alt>Return")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-by-type" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/Twp::setwallpaper" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/delete" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-ascending" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarActions/uca-action-1459954455527375-2" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/empty-trash" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-location-selector-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarLauncher/open-in-new-window" "<Primary><Shift>o")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/arrange-items-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/cut" "<Primary>x")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/close-window" "<Primary>q")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/select-all-files" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/open-location" "<Primary>l")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarStandardView/sort-by-mtime" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/zoom-reset" "<Primary>0")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-statusbar" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/show-hidden" "<Primary>h")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ThunarWindow/view-as-detailed-list" "<Primary>2")
```

Comment: F2 does the same thing in almost any graphical file manager.

Comment: It took me a bit of fiddling around to find the result since googling wouldn't work for this question, that's why I add it